# Pass multiple values to a string parameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, parameterized

Have a Jenkins job with a string parameter(P1), how do i pass multiple values to this parameter(P1=a,b,c..), I have to further pass the all values of P1 to my jenkins build step(a batch script) how can this be done?

Comment: Is your batch script an actual job or just a `sh './runScript.sh' step in a pipeline? And when you say pass multiple values, do you mean that P1 can be one of *any* a,b or c *OR* that P1 will have many values passed to it?

Comment: @auburn_moogle Hi Thanks for reply, my build step is execute windows batch command and there i call a .bat file.I want to be able to pass multiple input one after other to this batch file.(P1=a,b,c..) and my batch file should be able to run with all, where in a,b,c should come from user(user entering it,build wit parameter)

Comment: Okay. Last clarifying question: are you using a jenkins pipeline (scripted or declarative) or are you creating jobs in the jenkins GUI directly?

Comment: @auburn_moogle Sorry about delayed reply, creating job using GUI and now think to do this using perl script

Answer (score 0):

```
stage ('Invoke_pipeline') {
        steps {
            build job: 'test-docker-image',
                  parameters: [
            string(name: 'ProjectName', value: "atm"),
            string(name: 'Product', value:"renojournalman,reno-keymanagement,reno-management,renoalertman,reno-atm-update,reno-eventmonitor,reno-valmediamon"),
                    
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.